# Download file using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a submit button on a form, when it's pressed the form is submitted and an Excel file is created on the server harddrive (C:/ExcelFiles).

After this has been done (after de form is submitted) I want to download this file using Ajax.

This is what I've done but it's not working:

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveButton', function () {
$('#saveMessage').empty();
$('#saveMessage').append("<p>Your file has been stored in C:\\ExcelFiles</p>");
var data = $('#fileName').val();
alert(data);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Calculation/Download',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (returnValue) {
        window.location = '/Calculation/Download?fileName=' + returnValue;
    }
});
});
```

And my controller action look like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Download(string fileName)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFiles"), fileName);
        return File(fullPath, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
    }
```

Right now nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your doing an ajax `POST`, but you action method is restricted to `[HttpGet]` only, have you tried changing the ajax call to `GET` ?

Comment: Check out [this stackoverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax). Same issue and quite a few great answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot download files from the server by .ajax (due to security reasons).
You can however point the browser to that location and download the file.
The solution should be something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveButton', function () {
    $('#saveMessage').empty();
    $('#saveMessage').append("<p>Your file has been stored in C:\\ExcelFiles</p>");
    var data = $('#fileName').val();
    window.location = '/Calculation/Download?fileName=' + data ;
});
```

Comment: I get "Could not find file in ...." But when I check at the directory the file is there

Comment: Are you sending the extension with the file name?